# Image Staganography Algorithms

Tags: image, algorithm, methods, steganography

I am doing the research about Image Steganography. I have researched about S-Tools, ImaheHide and other related to Image Steganography tools. However, I am trying to find what are the methods can be used to hide the secret message inside the Image. So far I found out that most and maybe all of the today's Steganography tools are using Least Significant Bit (LSB) algorithm. But I cannot find other similar Steganography algorithms like LSB. I would appreciate if some of you can name other similar methods like LSB.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on topic because [its scope isn't specific enough](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Regardless, have you read any review articles on steganography as a starting point? Something like [this](http://www.jiit.ac.in/jiit/ic3/IC3_2008/IC3-2008/APP2_21.pdf), for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to change the least significant 2 or 3 bits, which is not really visually detectable, especially in camera photos. If you want, I can provide source code (in C).

Comment: This isn't exactly answering the question at hand. The question is what other methods, other than LSB substitution, can be used for steganography. Whether you change only the least significant, or the least two significant bits, it still makes it lsb substitution/replacement/switch.